# C - fgets() keeps skipping lines randomly when using the most basic case

Tags: c, csv, multidimensional-array, file-read

Before you remove it, I haven't seen this in any thread. I've seen people who wants to skips line but it fails, or it fails if there's a user input (which is due to weird input buffer thing in stdlibc... But not a case of `fgets` outright not working)

So, I need help, or for someone to tell me that the code works and that I need to reinstall everything on my PC or something.

At the start, I just wanted to quickly code a CSV -> 2D `float` array program in C.
Just because it would be neater then manually inputing an array in `main`. So, Tried to look for already made code. Couldn't find it. Tried to make it myself from scratch. Shouldn't be too bad I thought. I already did things similar.

But nothing worked. Here's what I tried.

I originally tried to just `fread` the whole file into a single `char *` array.
Didn't work either.

When I printed using `%d`, I got the whole array (except for newline character, ascii code 10, which didn't appear, even when reading in binary mode) I needed `'\n'` in the char array to `split("\n")` into different lines, but hey, I guess that's life)

To further add to my confusion, When I printed using `%c` or `%s` I only got the last line.

So Seeing that `fread` didn't work, I tried again, with `fgets`.
Used lots of code until I simplified it to the most basic case and it's still not working.

It's a really weird issues. Either I'm missing something and I'm too tired to see it, or The C compiler got updated with a bug.
After looking online and trying for hours, I didn't find a single post about this. It's weird, because `fgets` used to work on previous project. I tried restarting my PC and even compiling for linux and windows. Both doesn't work.

Here's a CSV file content.

**2D_data.csv**:

```
0.1,0.2,0.3
1.1,2.2,3.3
```

and here's the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

void readCSV(char *filename, int lineSize)
{
    FILE *filePointer = fopen(filename, "rb");
    char line[lineSize];

    fgets(line, lineSize, filePointer);
    printf("%s|\n", line);
}

void main()
{
    printf("\n\n------------START OF PROGRAM------------\n\n");
    readCSV("2D_data.csv", 128);
}
```

and I get the output:

```
1.1,2.2,3.3|
```

when it should be the first line of the file aka

```
0.1,0.2,0.3|
```

Comment: I also got a bunch of weird stuff such as when I printed

`printf("%d___ %s\n",i,line);`
The i didn't appear and the ___ didn't appear.

fgets and fread are just cursed.

Comment: If you created the file on Windows and try and read it on Linux you'll have issues because of the Windows style line endings. Run `dos2unix` on it and try again.

Comment: well, I created it in windows.
But I tested code on windows and linux.
Also, the issues is that fgets isn't behaving as it should.

Comment: Old versions of Mac OS used CR as the the line termination (instead of CRLF or LF)... Try printing the `strlen()` of what is loaded...

Comment: Don't open it in binary mode on Windows or it won't translate the cr/lf pair to `\n` and the cr will cause it to print on the same line again.

Comment: I tried to create a CSV in ubuntu subsystem and then compile and ran it on the ubuntu subsystem and fgets did work.

Comment: Works fine here reading from stdin. https://godbolt.org/z/e8fxne1hh Since you're not removing the `\n` that `fgets` reads the `|` will be on the next line.

Comment: first line: 
1.1,2.2,3.3|
24
where 24 is the str len. 
It seems it holds the content of the previous line and the current line (which it shouldn't) with a cursed print on top

Comment: Bad data... Use a decent editor to create your data file. One that doesn't save the file with CR (only) as the line terminator...

Comment: There's something wrong with your file. Sounds like it doesn't have linefeeds, only carriage returns which aren't considered and EOL by `fgets` and which would cause the second line to print over the first. Without a hex dump of your actual file that is the best guess.

Comment: sounds like you may be running into the age-old running an out-of-date version of the program.  Double-check that the executable is updated.  Even remove it and then rebuild it.

Comment: No ash, I deleted all exe file and reran multiple time before i posted here, just redid it.  It seems to be Windows being very stupid at defining newline in textfile. Thank you for caring though.

Comment: AND NOW IT WORKS with a .text created in  windows...

Comment: and now it works if i rename a .txt to a .csv
The original csv however, still breaks the code.

The original csv was created using Excel -> Save as CSV. 
I thought it was the best way to do it...

Seems like thats the problem

Comment: – 
Fe2O3 YOU ARE A GENIUS!

So, the problem was that I accidentally saved the CSV file i created in excel as a macintosh.csv (I just backpedalled. Made a new file .windows dos and it worked. Exact same problem with macintosh).

Comment: @Selflearningstudent "_They wouldn't listen to the fact that I was a genius/Said they got all that they can use/Now I got those steadily depressin', low down, mind messin', workin' at the Car Wash blues..._" -- Jim Croce... Gone but not forgotten... `:-)`

Comment: None of us is a genius. Some of us are simply old enough to have seen this before.

Comment: BTW, if your compiler isn't complaining about [`void main()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c), you should rise its warning level.

Answer (score 0):

Huh, I seems it's because lineSize > 1 line...
Still, how do you get a buffer that's big enough to hold any line and not
overflow on newline?

Isn't fgets supposed to stop at newline character?

---

New comment: File created in linux, code compiled and ran in linux (Windows Ubuntu Subsystem). This is the previous code, I just didn't strip it down even further.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    int size;
    char *string;
} Line;

typedef struct
{
    Line *LineArray;
    int hor; // number of element horizontally (m)
    int ver; // number of element vertically;
    float **data_matrix;
} CSV;


CSV *readCSV(char *filename, int lineSize)
{

    CSV *csv = malloc(sizeof(CSV));
    csv->hor = csv->ver = 0;



    FILE *filePointer = fopen(filename, "rb");
    char line[lineSize];



    while (fgets(line, lineSize, filePointer) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s",line);
    }
    return csv;
}

void main()
{
    printf("\n\n------------START OF PROGRAM------------\n\n");
    readCSV("data.csv",128);
}
```

data.csv (created in linux)

```
0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5
1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5
2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5
3.1,3.2,3.3
4.1,4.2
```

Output (compile and ran in linux)

```
------------START OF PROGRAM------------

0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5
1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5
2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5
3.1,3.2,3.3
4.1,4.2
```

But for file created in windows, it still can't work.
Is there any solution other then "Windows Bad" ?
I don't wanna have to use my linux subsystem everytime i do C coding.

New Edit: The code does work When ran in windows, if the csv was created in linux. wtf

Final Edit: It was due to a mac CSV encoding. See my other answer.
Thanky you to everyone

Comment: Windows line endings are `\r\n` on disk. Linux line endings are `\n`. If you don't open the file in binary mode on Windows it will translate the line ending pair to `\n` when it reads that data. If you want to use that file on Linux you can convert it to Linux style line endings with the `dos2unix` program. You could also use an editor like Notepad++ to save the file with Linux line endings on Windows then it would work on either.

Comment: FYI -- this code works 100% on windows 10, MS Visual Studio C.  Exact same output as you got.  File is also created in Win 10.

Comment: @Self learning student, Suggest "didn't stip it down" --> "didn't strip it down".

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
Solution: No problem with the code

It's because I wanted to be safe and created a CSV file from excel and saved as CSV. However, I missclicked the Mac CSV options rather then the windows CSV options.

Hence, When compiled on windows or Linux, the newline being a different character, doesn't get caught.

Moral of the story: Manually write your CSV with a texteditor next time.

Comment: "Moral of the story: Manually write your CSV with a texteditor next time." or use input functions tolerant of various line endings.

Comment: Please give example of C function that are tolerant to various line endings.
If they aren't in libC, then you need to make your own function. What Lib C function would you use inside of it? 

Like, the core function to split with varying newline. 
Or do you make a function for that too using if statement?

Comment: Self learning student, `fscanf("%" WIDTH_AS_A_STRING "[^\n\r]", buf)` is a starting point with additional supporting code.  The issue become, does one adjust the code to accommodate data or adjust the data to accommodate code.  This answer supports the 2nd. I am suggesting the first.  Your call.